# nextjs上のサーバーサイドでsupabaseのデータをフェッチする方法について

Tags: reactjs, next.js

supabase上にpostsというテーブルを作成し、３つデータを追加しました。
そのうえでsupabase上でpostsのデータをすべて取得したいと思い以下のコードを実行すると取得したデータが空になってしまします。

```
const { data: posts } = await supabase.from("posts").select("*");
```

```
データの返り値
{ error: null, data: [], count: null, status: 200, statusText: '' }
```

しかし、以下のようにrange(0,10)を追加すると正常にデータを取得できます。

```
const { data: posts } = await supabase.from("posts").select("*").range(0, 10);
```

なぜ１つ目のコードでは正常にデータ取得できないのでしょうか？
教えていただけると幸いです。